# Redmine do not show Git revisions

Tags: ruby, git, redmine

I've got troubles with my Redmine when installed new version. There are nothing about to show Git revision. Only files, see the screenshots attached to this message.

[image][image][image][image]

In Redmine logs I found it:[image]

Attempt to fine the cause of it game me this:[image]

My environment:[image]

Could anyone help me to solve it?